# Predicting from mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, predictive-models, prediction, lme4-nlme

I have yield data of a crop for 10 sites and 15 years. I will try to reproduce the data here.

```
site <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),each=15)
year <- rep(1996:2010,times=10)
yield <- runif(150,1000,4000)
water.stress <- runif(150,-20,20)
dat <- data.frame(site,year,yield,water.stress)
```

I model `yield` as a function of `water stress` and using `site` and `year` as random effect.

```
mdl <- lmer(yield ~ water.stress + (1|site) + (1|year),dat=dat)
```

I am interested in knowing whether the sensitivity of yield to water stress has increased in recent years. 
This is because each year, a different variety of crop was grown and I expect that the more recent variety
would be more sensitive to water stress.

To test this, I use my `mdl` to predict yield for each `year`. For example,

```
 dat1 <- dat 
 dat1$year <- 1996 # predict for year 1996. 
 pred <- predict(mdl, newdata=dat, re.form=(~1|year),allow.new.levels=TRUE) 
 # this will predict for year 1996
 yld <- mean(pred) # take the mean of the prediction of 1996.
```

Putting this in a loop to calculate for each year.

```
dat$pred <- 0

for(j in 1996:2010){
  dat1 <- dat 
  dat1$year <- j
  pred <- predict(mdl, newdata=dat, re.form=(~1|year),allow.new.levels=TRUE) 
  # this will predict for each year of the loop
  yld<-mean(pred)
  dat[dat[,2]==j,5] <- yld
}
```

If I calculate the slope of mean yield each year against year using `lm(dat$yld ~ dat$year)` and if 
the slope comes out to be negative (and significant) does it imply that sensitivity to water stress has increased over time.

or does the slope of linear model tell me whether the sensitivity towards water stress have changed over time?

The random data generated is not correct. I just need a bit of advise on my method/design.

Comment: If you suspect and are interested in temporal trends, you should include `year` as a fixed effect and not as a random effect, although not necessarily a linear one (you could try a GAMM).

Comment: Thank you. If I use year as fixed effect, does the statistical design seem correct to test my hypothesis?